# recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions

Tags: python, opencv, windows-10, pyinstaller

I have a small program which return opencv error after compilation by pyinstaller.
But without compilation it's work!

I use Python 3.8.10 on Windows 10

**Program:**

import pyautogui
import numpy as np
import cv2
try:
from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
import Image

screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot('screenshot.png', region=(970, 591, 184, 101)) # start 
img = cv2.imread('screenshot.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)

**Error:**

['C:\Users\n1kro\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI83642\base_library.zip', 'C:\Users\n1kro\AppData\Local\Temp\*MEI83642\lib-dynload', 'C:\Users\n1kro\AppData\Local\Temp\*MEI83642']  
                                                Traceback (most recent call last):     
                                                                                   File "test.py", line 3, in           
                                                                           File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module   
                                            File "cv2_*init**.py", line 180, in                
                                                            File "cv2_*init**.py", line 75, in bootstrap               
                                                          ImportError: ERROR: recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions. Check OpenCV installation.         [3416] Failed to execute script 'test' due to unhandled exception!

I tried to reinstall all, but it is not helped!

Find this post: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13202
But dont understand, what to do :(
Need your help, please!

Comment: Same problem here

Answer (score 17):

open cmd and use pip to install a different version:

```
 pip install opencv-python==4.5.3.56
```

no problems with pyinstaller after it

Comment: It worked for me with combination of Windows 11, "Python 3.7.13", "opencv-python 4.5.3.56", "pyinstaller 5.2", "pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2022.8" - https://github.com/cppxaxa/pyinstaller-opencv

Answer (score 7):

To get around this issue, you can either:

- Use an older version of OpenCV (e.g. `opencv-python==4.5.3.56` instead of `4.6.0.66`) as mentioned by the others.
- Wait for a new version of `PyInstaller` and `pyinstaller-hooks-contrib` (possibly v5.3 and v2022.9 according to https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6964#issuecomment-1193333632).
- Install and compile the development build of pyInstaller that contains a fix for this issue (see thread in comment linked above).

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this by uninstalling opencv and installing an older version. Version 4.5.3 worked well.