# When I try to convert my .py file to a .exe, it gives an error when I try to run it

Tags: python, opencv, pyinstaller

When I try to convert my .py file to .exe, it all works smoothly until I try running the .exe file. INFO: ERROR: recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions. Check OpenCv installation. The pyinstaller command I used was "pyinstaller main.py --onefile -w". Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69855356/9705687) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72997422/9705687). In one case, they went with a lower version of OpenCV and in another case they went with a lower version of Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) to set up your python environment. Start the Anaconda Powershell Prompt and run:

`conda install -c conda-forge opencv pyinstaller`

to install the opencv and pyinstaller. After that, try build your scripts.

`pyinstaller.exe main.py`

Comment: That worked, thanks! I did come accross another issue after that though. It says that "Mediapipe not found" Mediapipe is a module I'm using in my script, do you maybe have a solution to that, too? I took the command you gave me but changed opencv to mediapipe and tried. Didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: @bixenithh for those can not install via conda, just use pip install: `pip install mediapipe`