# PyInstaller exe error ImportError: recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions. Check OpenCV installation

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pyinstaller

I'm trying to package a python program as an .exe with pyinstaller. I need to use onefile, It has to be distributed on other computers and I will not be able to use onedir.
The program works as a .py but not as .exe
I am also using a venv
I'm on windows.

I'm using this command to package as exe:

```
pyinstaller prog.spec --clean --noconfirm
```

After running the exe it comes up with an ImportError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 4, in <module>
    import easyocr

 File "cv2\__init__.py", line 76, in bootstrap
    raise ImportError('ERROR: recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions. Check OpenCV installation.')
ImportError: ERROR: recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions. Check OpenCV installation.
```

The error originates from easyocr.
I've tried googling the error and I've tried those solutions but it doesnt work for me.
I've tried reinstalling all requirements, and also using different versions of some modules.
It seems to maybe be some sort of issue with numpy being imported multiple times as its a dependency of a few of my used modules.

printing out sys.modules gives output like this:

```
'C:\\Users\\john\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\torchvision\\version.py'>,
```

So it seems that the program is trying to use the packages from my main python installation instead of the venv installations. How do I fix this so that it would use the venv modules?

update edit:
I downgraded to python 3.7.9.
My spec file is below. I was receiving "File exists but should not" errors. So i had to manually remove those entries

```
a = Analysis(['prog.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

datas_upd = TOC()
#x = 'cp310-win_amd64.pyd' #Pvthon 3.10 gave errors with these files
#y = 'flatbuffer.cp310-win_amd64.pyd'
x = "_C.pyd" #Python 3.7.9 gave errors with these files
y = "_C_flatbuffer.pyd"

for d in a.datas:
    if (x not in d[0] and x not in d[1]) and (y not in d[0] and y not in d[1]):
        datas_upd.append(d)

a.datas = datas_upd
...
```

After downgrading python and running the new .exe, I get this error instead:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\john\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI68602\\easyocr\\character\\en_char.txt'
```

Comment: Try lowering your python version to 3.7.9. Because 3.10 version has some issues when using OpenCV

Comment: I tried that, and it now gives a different error. I added it to the post

Comment: Well? Does that file exist in that directory?

Comment: It does exist in the directory before turning into .exe. Sometimes, I've been unable to find the _MEIxxxx that throws the FileNotFound, but when I have found the folder, the file does exist.

Comment: I've given up on trying to solve this issue. Not worth the time it's taking